# Can I use C# 7.2 in modifier instead of IntPtr?

Tags: c#, marshalling

I use this native DLL that exports 2 functions:

```c
int str_get(char** strPtr); // to allocate and return a string
void str_free(char* str); // to free the above string
```

I marshal these functions in C# as:

```c#
int str_get(out IntPtr str);
void str_free(IntPtr str);
```

... then use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to get the string. This works as expected.

I can also marshal the "get" function as:

```c#
int str_get(out string str)
```

This way I can get the string directly without using `Marshal`. What I can't figure out though is how to call the "free" function in this case. I was thinking I need to marshal it differently, perhaps using the `in` modifier in C# 7.2 either as `in string` or `in char`. It does not work either way, or I don't know how to call it.

So I have to ask: is it possible at all? And if it is, how?

Comment: You free the memory in the way that matches the way in which it was allocated. .NET provides `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem` and `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`, so allocate the memory with `CoTaskMemAlloc` or `LocalAlloc` on the C++ side.

Comment: The native DLL is a 3rd party. I do not need to know how it works. I just have to call the free function from C#.

Comment: *The* free function depends on how the memory was allocated inside the library. When a library allocates memory for the caller, it is usually specified in the library's documentation how to free that memory. [*The runtime always uses the `CoTaskMemFree` method to free memory. If the memory you are working with was not allocated with the `CoTaskMemAlloc` method, you must use an `IntPtr` and free the memory manually using the appropriate method.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior#memory-management-with-the-interop-marshaler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work. When you marshal between `char*` and `string`, the marshaler will allocate a new managed string object or unmanaged memory, and copy the data over.

The matching p/invoke signature for `void str_free(char* str);` would simply be `void str_free(string str)`, but the `char*` pointer passed to `str_free` wouldn't be the same that was returned by `str_get`. It would point to a different copy of the data that was allocated by the CLR rather than the native DLL, and the free would almost certainly fail.